# Row groups collapsing on row/cell editing in mui DataGridPro treeData

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-x-data-grid

I'm facing some issues with collapsible row groups in MUI DataGridPro.

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/serverless-hill-yzzdfk

[Actual]: If you expand all row groups and start editing any nested row, all other groups will close.
[Expected]: Groups should remain open when editing one of the rows (switching mode to 'edit').
Any ideas?